Ag grid: placeholder text for custom filter options
There is a column receiving a timestamp value in the format of YYYY-MM-DD, hh:mm:ss [AM/PM]. An example of this format is 2024-01-01, 02:04:05 AM. I need to add a custom filter option to filter out range values for such data, which can take from and to timestamp values and return the filtered result.
I am trying with filterOptions in filterParams` as per below, which seem to work. Is there a way to specify placeholder text for the two custom filter inputs?
{
  field: 'timestampColumn',
  filterParams: {
    filterOptions: [
      {
        displayKey: 'inRange',
        displayName: 'In range',
        predicate: ([filterFromDate, filterToDate], cellValue) => {
          const cellDate = new Date(cellValue); 
          const startDate = new Date(filterFromDate);
          const endDate = new Date(filterToDate);
          return cellDate > startDate && cellDate < endDate;
        },
        numberOfInputs: 2,
      },
    ],
  },
},


To add placeholder text for the two custom filter inputs in your filterParams configuration, you can use the inputPlaceholders property within the filterOptions object. Here's how you can modify your existing code to include placeholders:
{
  field: 'timestampColumn',
  filterParams: {
    filterOptions: [
      {
        displayKey: 'inRange',
        displayName: 'In range',
        predicate: ([filterFromDate, filterToDate], cellValue) => {
          const cellDate = new Date(cellValue); 
          const startDate = new Date(filterFromDate);
          const endDate = new Date(filterToDate);
          return cellDate > startDate && cellDate < endDate;
        },
        numberOfInputs: 2,
        inputPlaceholders: ['From Date', 'To Date'], // Add placeholders here
      },
    ],
  },
},

This will display "From Date" and "To Date" as placeholder text in the two input fields for your custom filter.
